# Generate the required directories while saving files with Files.writeString

Tags: java, java-nio

I am saving a string as a file.

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

String data = "hello, world";
Files.writeString(Path.of("upload-dir", "xyz", "abc", "data.txt"), data);
```

I get the following error as `xyz` and `abc` are not present.

`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: upload-dir/xyz/abc/data.txt`

Is there a way to get this method to create those directories as well automatically (not by calling `Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());`?

Comment: No.  That is literally what createDirectories is for.

Comment: writeString also takes some options. So, I assumed it would be possible.

Comment: If you just want to create a single file (not directories) then use an [OpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html) `Files.writeString(Path.of(path), data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);` however, if you want to create an entire path you need to use `Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());` it's a simple matter to add a check if directories exist and call that before you attempt to write the file